# Interesting probability expectation question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Six individuals, including $A$ and $B$, take seats around a circular table iat random. Suppose the seats are numbered $1,...,6$. Let $X=A$'s seat number and $Y=B$'s seat number. If $A$ sends a written message around the table to $B$ in the direction in which they are closest, how many individuals (including $A$ and $B$) would you expect to handle the message? I'm completely stumped I'm trying to come up with a connection between $X$ and $Y$ but I can't think of one. I tried to make a joint probability table of the probability that each kind of arrangement would work, but I can't get them all to equal one (yes I did take into account they can't sit in the same seat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality $A$ is sitting in seat $1$. Person $B$ is equally likely to be in any of the $5$ remaining seats. Let $X$ be the number of people who handle the message.

We have $\Pr(X=2)=\frac{2}{5}$, $\Pr(X=3)=\frac{2}{5}$, and $\Pr(X=4)=\frac{1}{5}$.

Now I expect you can compute the expectation of $X$.

Comment: Wow that simple. I was starting to get toward that thought, but thanks!